# call variable from codebehind inside DataTemplate with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

It would recover from the codebehind **firstGrid** and **secondGrid** objects.
But these are inside a DataTemplate, as I can recall them from the codebehind?

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<control:CarouselView x:Name="carouselView">
                            <control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="46*"></RowDefinition>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"></RowDefinition>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="53.8*"></RowDefinition>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <!-- griglia del carousel, tutta la struttura inizia qui-->
                                        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="45*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Button Image="backBlueArrow.png" BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="clickmePrev" Grid.Column="0"></Button>
                                            <!--<Image Source="backBlueArrow.png" x:Name="backClickArrow" Aspect="AspectFit" Grid.Column="0"></Image>-->
                                            <StackLayout Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" Grid.Column="1">
                                                <Image HeightRequest="70" Source="{Binding Immagine}" Aspect="AspectFit"></Image>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                            <!-- griglia superiore, riprende i dati tra le barre bianche-->
                                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="40*"></RowDefinition>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="60*"></RowDefinition>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Descrizione}" Margin="{Binding Margine}" TextColor="#fff" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Valore}" FontSize="Large" TextColor="#fff" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                                <Image Margin="-25,-5,0,0" Source="{Binding ImmagineBatteriaEmoticon}" HeightRequest="50" x:Name="emoticonBattery" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"></Image>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Button Image="nextBlueArrow.png" BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="clickmeNext" Grid.Column="3"></Button>
                                            <!--<Image Source="nextBlueArrow.png" x:Name="nextClickArrow" Aspect="AspectFit" Grid.Column="3"></Image>-->
                                        </Grid>
                                        <!-- griglia fare la riga bianca -->
                                        <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="1">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <!-- griglia inferiore, ritrare i dati dei testi -->
                                        <ScrollView Grid.Row="2">
                                            <Grid Padding="5" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="firstGrid">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="65*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Testo1}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Valore1}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Testo2}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Valore2}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Testo3}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Valore3}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Testo4}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Valore4}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Testo5}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Valore5}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding Testo6}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding Valore6}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding Testo7}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding Valore7}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Text="{Binding Testo8}"></Label>
                                                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="End" TextColor="#5B6667" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Text="{Binding Valore8}"></Label>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <RelativeLayout Grid.Row="2" x:Name="secondGrid" BackgroundColor="Fuchsia" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100">
                                                <Label Text="ciao"></Label>
                                            </RelativeLayout>
                                        </ScrollView>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <!--<Label Text="{Binding Testo}" />-->
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </control:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        </control:CarouselView>
```

Warning: Before that is duplicated, the code is for Xamarin forms pcl. Which it is slightly different from c # with WPF.

thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the grids? Maybe we can find a workaround

Comment: I have to call her back to hide it according to index the carousel.

Comment: Add a property isVisible to your viewmodel and set it accordingly

Comment: I don't use ViewModel. I've need to call objetc from Name, but it's not possibile. I must find another solution

Answer (score 1):

When you use a DataTemplate, the binding concern the object you are binding and not the ViewModel you may have used.

But fear not, as Xamarin provides us ways to attach treatements to this kind of objects !

Let's say you want to click your image :

```
<Button Image="nextBlueArrow.png" BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="clickmeNext" Grid.Column="3"></Button>
```

May become

```
<Image Source="nextBlueArrow.png">
   <Image.GestureRecognizers>
     <TapGestureRecognizer
       Tapped="clickmeNext"
       CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
     </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

With the clickmeNext method in your code behind like this :

```
public async void clickmeNext(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            Image imageSender = (Image)sender;
            YourObject yourObject= (YourObject )imageSender.BindingContext;

            //some actions on your instance of YourObject, 
            //which is the instance linked to the image
        }
```

If I did not answer your question, don't hesitate to add to your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Yup, here he was speaking about code behind and not ViewModel but the method you showed should work... :)

Comment: This event start when you click...don't for me